# how to control a combo box by using another combo box swing

Tags: java, swing

I have two combo box the items first one is (women and men).I want when user select women in first combo box the list of women's dress will appear in second combo box and when men is selected the list of men's dress will appear in second one.Can do this functionality by using JCombo box? if yes how can I do that give me example please.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out how to work with models in [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) totorials. According to a selection in the first combo box - rebuild, filter or perhaps replace the model of the second combo box. You can use/extend [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) - a default model used by a `JComboBox`. For example consider this snippet:

```
final JComboBox genderComboBox = null;
final JComboBox itemComboBox = null;

final DefaultComboBoxModel hisModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel herModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"x", "y", "z"});

genderComboBox.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("Men".equals(genderComboBox.getSelectedItem())){
            itemComboBox.setModel(hisModel);    
        } else {
            itemComboBox.setModel(herModel);    
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, upon selection in the first combo you can rebuild the items in the second one manually, ie: using `JComboBox` methods `removeAllItems()` and `addItem()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **add event listener to the first combobox**. This way you will know when its selection changes,  you can interrogate it and fill your second combobox out with appropriate data.

More information is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners